# QGraphicsView rendering its sub widget's sub widget weirdly

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm working on a music/MIDI editor using C++ and Qt.
The develop was smooth until I met an issue that QGraphicsView is rendering weirdly with its child widget's child widget.
(wow, that's confusing)

This is the code I used to add my sub widgets to a QGraphicsView

```
pianoPlain = new QawPianoPlain();
keyBoard = new QawPianoKeyBoard();
scene->addWidget(pianoPlain);
scene->addWidget(keyBoard);


keyBoard->setGeometry(0,0,100,540);
keyBoard->setKeyNum(36);

pianoPlain->setGeometry(100,0,500,540);
pianoPlain->setStriptNum(36);
```

The code makes something like this.
pianoRoll -> keyBoard -> key 
...............|-> pianoPlaom -> noteStript

Where pianoPlain and keyBoard are classes I inherit from GraphicsView and key and noteStript are both inherit from QWidget.

Here is a picture of what happens:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYLJIsbhhuVZ0RMdzRqV01Cd2M/view?usp=sharing

And this is picture of a normal keyBoard which is placed directy in MainWindow(left) and a screwed up one placed in QGraphicsView(right)
(I have disable back/while key in this picture)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYLJIsbhhuVSDFhSXRVM0dHWnM/view?usp=sharing

It seems that whenever pianoPlain and keyBoard are placed in a QGtraphicsView, it will be screwed.
Anyone know what's happening? How can I fix this?

Qt : 5.4.1
OS : KUubutu 15.04 AMD64
Compiler : clang 3.6.0/ GCC 4.9.2

Comment: Just to clarify, are you adding `QGraphicsView` widgets as items to a `QGraphicsScene`!?

Comment: Yes, I add my widget to the scen. (Since there is a addWidget, why not?) Is this why things are going wrong?

Comment: Either the scene isn't accommodating your rendered items correctly or your code for the sub-widgets may have bugs. I suggest creating a sample sub-widget and adding that to the scene to test whether it's a problem with your scene's layout or a problem with your sub-widgets.

Comment: After some test. I don't think it's my widget's issue. Even QPushButton arn't rendering correctly if they are placed in QGraphicsView's grandchild widget.
[link to picture](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzYLJIsbhhuVUzFVT01QZG4tc28/view?usp=sharing)

As you can see, Button 2 is not rendered

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest pianoPlain and keyBoard should use a class that inherits QGraphicsItem - for example QGraphicsPixmapItem or QGraphicsProxyWidget.

You then would add these to the scene using your scene->addWidget() method.

The scene itself should then be part of a QGraphicsView.

For example:

```
QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView();
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);

view->setScene(scene_);

// No need to parent these
pianoPlain = new QawPianoPlain();
keyBoard = new QawPianoKeyBoard();

// This will work if QawPianoPlain and QawPianoKeyBoard inherit QWidget
QGraphicsProxyWidget* pianoProxy = scene_->addWidget(pianoPlain);
QGraphicsProxyWidget* keyBoardProxy = scene_->addWidget(keyBoard );
```

Use the proxy widget for any transformations/animations.

Comment: No, I'm not doing any transformations/animations. I'm just adding widget to a QGraphicsView where the QGraphicsView is a child widget of another QGraphicsView's scene.
In this case. Even the plain old QPushButton isn't rendering properly.